# Reverse a number inside a string in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, reverse

I have a UTF8 string that contains letters and digits. For example:

`"Hello World 37. What? 24 last 6650"`

and I want to reverse only the digits but keep the numbers in the same place.
The output should be:

`"Hello World 73. What? 42 last 0566"`

Comment: Sounds like a case for preg_replace_callback()

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Why down vote? It took me only 2 mins to post my own solution.

Comment: FYI: There's an "Answer your own question" checkbox when posting a question, for exactly this reason... :)

Comment: @deceze, I didn't notice. Will use it next time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', function (array $m) { return strrev($m[0]); }, $string);
```

Comment: On one hand I like the fact that your solution is shorter and uses a known function, on the other hand, I like my solution since for me it's easier to understand. I checked the 2 solutions performance and they both gave the same result - 5 sec each give or take a few milliseconds.

Comment: I would argue that this one here is *a lot easier* to understand, if you understand what `preg_replace_callback` does. It pretty explicitly expresses *"find all numbers and reverse them"*. Yours says *"explode, then loop, then check this, that and the other thing, then reverse something, then concatenate it..."* - it's many more steps which makes the overall workings of the algorithm harder to comprehend. Anyone trained in the art can quickly see what this regex replacement does. But everyone has to do mental gymnastics to follow your multi-step process.

Answer (score 0):

Before I posted the question, I thought about it and got an idea that works for me, so I'm only posting this question to enrich the database.

```
function reverseNumbersInString($str){
    $tokens = explode(" ", $str);
    $res = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($tokens); $i++){
        if (intval($tokens[$i] > 0 )){
            $tokens[$i] = strrev($tokens[$i]);
        }
        $res .= " " . $tokens[$i];
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Nice. But I like deceze's better ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$stringWithReversedNumbers = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\d+/',
    function ($matches) {
        return strrev($matches[0]);
    },
    $originalString
);
```

Alternatively, if you ONLY want to operate on numbers that are distinct words (i.e. not part of another word, as in if you want `hello123goodbye` to remain unmodified because the 123 isn't a word by itself), change `\d+` to `\b\d+\b`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$string = "Hello World 37. What? 24 last 6650";

preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

foreach ($matches[0] as $numberData) {
    $numberArray = str_split($numberData[0]);
    $reversedNumber = implode('', array_reverse($numberArray));
    $string = substr_replace($string, $reversedNumber, $numberData[1], strlen($numberData[0]));
}
```